# Content negotiation not working with respond_to stanza

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Good afternoon Stack Overflow,

```
def show
   # Translating ID to event
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.json { render :json => @event }
   end
end
```

This code should (according to what I read online) generate an html response when the `Accept` header is set to `text/html`, and JSON whenever the header is set to `application/json`. Yet whenever I test this with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) I always end up getting the representation of the resource that is set first.

In the above code that would be html, even when the accept header is set solely to Json. If I switch them around, I get a json representation, indifferent of what I set the header.

Side question: I'm kinda new to Ruby, and would like to fully understand what the `do |x| do_a() do_b()` syntax/stanza is. Is this like a Switch statement or more a lambda?

Comment: Did you append `?format=json` or `.json` to the URL? Because if so, the format will be json even if the Accept header says otherwise

Comment: @Yoones No, I haven't. Yet isn't the point of having content negotiation that the client can request a resource on 1 url in infinite forms? Eg: domain.com/myPoem with Accept: text/html should return the human readable HTML version and domain.com/myPoem with Accept: application/json should return my beautifull poem in a JSON representation?

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't forbid you from chosing, in your application's routes, specific formats depending on you needs (it's the `(.:format)` you see when you run `rake routes`)

Comment: @yoones Thx for your reply, so what does this mean for my code? You mean the content negotiation works atm if eg a JS bot tries to acces my resource with Accept: Application/json (without the extension on the URL/URI )? Yet if I wanna test my code I'd need to add `.json`? As you mentioned the `(.:format)` is there whenever I run `rake routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found

My brain just gave out for 2 days, because apparently I was sending Content-Type headers in a GET request, instead of the appropriate Accept Header.

Thx @yoones for trying to help me :)